# What current secular professions still maintain titles like 'Sister' and 'Brother'?

Tags: titles

I was surprised at seeing BrE speakers calling nurses - *sister(s)*, then I came across this E.SE page:

[What is the original connection between "nurse" and "sister"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373426/what-is-the-original-connection-between-nurse-and-sister)

which got me thinking:

What current secular professions still maintain titles like 'Sister' and 'Brother'?

Comment: That’s an odd use of *now*. Do you mean *current* or *new* or what?

Comment: @Clare yes, currently

Comment: Sargent, corporal, private, doctor, professor, counselor.

Comment: Are you asking if people call out for a person with a profession name, similar to calling out for a nurse by saying 'Sister!' or are you asking if there are other _religious_ labels that are used for calling for people by profession in secular settings?

Comment: @Mitch the first one - seeing if ‘Sister’ (and ‘Brother’) are used in other secular professions

Comment: @user3306356 To clarify, do you mean if you might call someone 'Sister Mary' for some profession other than say nurse? So not _like_ (similar to) Brother or Sister but those two words exactly?

Comment: not similar to, no. just exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

*Clerk* is the only other example I can think of, though there's more distance in both time and mutation of meaning than with *Sister*.

The religious sense of *clerk* is the original, and the other sense derived from those as originally account-keeping and secretarial work would be done largely by people who were clerks in that sense, and the term remained when they became lay professions and was then applied to yet further roles.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this religious sense of 'clerk'? I had no idea that it was ever so connected.

Comment: @Mitch https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clerk#Noun gives the first definition as "a cleric or clergyman". For how the path of the word happened, its notable that while used for anyone of the 8 orders, but sometimes excluding bishops and above, it was also sometimes only of the minor orders like acolyte and lector (just which orders are which and which are in use at all had a few changes over history). Such people would often do jobs for the Church or even the state that would now still be called clerical work when done by laity for businesses, etc.

Comment: Jon, this must be a UK/US difference. Wiktionary (though questionable) modifies that first definition as _archaic_, which I agree with; outside of very religious or historical contexts, there is no intimation of religious connection in the US. Also, the OP is asking if currently _and_ secularly would 'sister' or 'brother' be used with it, and in the US that is certainly _not_ the case for a person called a clerk (a bookkeeper or information processor).

Comment: @Mitch the question asked that the secular title be the one that's current, and that's definitely still current in the US ("clerk of court" is certainly a title there), but for the religious use the American Episcopal Church has clerks.

Comment: Jon: It's still not clear to me. Do people still address these clerks in the US system (courts and, separately, religious) as 'Sister' or 'Brother'?

Comment: @Mitch, they refer to them as "clerks", which is a religious title that became a job, as "sister" did.

Comment: Jon: so then do you refer to a clerk whose name is Bob as 'Brother Bob'? That is the OPs question. Do you use the title 'Brother' or 'Sister' with a person who is a clerk?

Comment: @Mitch, it says "titles like Brother and Sister", *clerk* is a job-title **like** Brother and Sister.

Comment: Jon: OK, but then you'd say that 'Doctor Smith' and 'General Miller' are equally good answers? I also don't think the OP is asking for this. Are you also saying that 'Clerk Jones' is something that is used?  I don't think 'clerk' is used this way (and it also doesn't feel religious to me). I've asked the OP for clarification.